# Important parameters formula in optuna hyperparameter optimization

Tags: hyperparameters, optuna

I use the optuna package to optimize my hyperparameters. I have a question about how to score important parameters. What formula is used to get the imporancy score of each hyperparameter? A score that is between zero and one.

Comment: it depends on your task; if regressor use `mae`,if detection use `iou`;if classification use standard metrics like `f1` or `recall` or `precision`

Comment: No, the questioner asks the definition of importance scores, not objective values.